# Problems performing union operations on polygons with shared edges in boost geometry

Tags: c++, boost, polygons, boost-geometry

I'm trying to use boost geometry to build vehicle ongoing path of constant width with self intersections calculations. Faced problems with result of boolean operations on polygons (more precisely multipolygon).

Here my path mpolygon on some step:
[image]

On every step I use two points x,y (floats) - left and right offseted by half of constant width from current vehicle location. Let's call x-y line a segment.

When location of vehicle is updated, I construct appended mpolygon using old x,y point and new ones, (correct it indeed) and union_ it with path mpolygon (so path mpolygon gets longer).

Sometimes (especially for large enough width values) there can be intersection of new segment with previous. In that cases I construct appended mpolygon as two polygons using calculated intersection point with bg::intersection of two segments: oldx-oldy line and x-y line.
[image]
And when I union_ it with path mpolygon there is first sign of a problem:
[image]
result is a two polygons within mpolygon, not the one as I expected. It appears not always, but quite often.

Next step, and again intersection of new segment with previous, and again construct two polygons in appended mpolygon
[image]

Union result - one polygon in mpolygon:
[image]

And one last step
[image]

Those almost zero areas can appear as "part" of outer ring of one polygon, or as a separate polygons in mpolygon within another biggest one (braking mpolygon model's rule).

I suppose this is in the end start causing overlay invalid input exceptions (that I get) when performing intersection or union_ with such mpolygon on the next steps.

Thinking that problem is in the floating point inaccuracy (that maybe calculates slightly different intersection point of polygons with shared edge when performing union_ ), I even trying to solve this by inserting intersection point of segments in outer ring of current path polygon before doing union_. It slightly reduces overlay invalid input exceptions when perform intersection or union_, but not solve problem completely.

Have anybody encountered with problems of that kind? If there any solution of such problems? Maybe in some other geometry libraries?

Sorry for long description.
Thank you very much in advance for help.

Comment: Post this problem into boost geometry mailing list
http://lists.boost.org/geometry/2016/04/3518.php and add bug report https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12118 (where you can find WKT representation of those illustrated polygons I posted, if somebody get interested).
I think finally this problems will be solved thanks to authors of boost geometry.

But it is still interesting, if there are problems of that kind in others geometry libraries in such cases?